# Bootstrap 4: data-keyboard="true" not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a [Bootstrap 4 carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) and I have given this attribute `data-keyboard="true"`

However the keyboard navigation does not work. Not even when focusing on the carousel itself with the mouse first.

I would like the carousel to work with keyboard directly on page load.

This is my code

```
<?php if( have_rows('photos') ): ?>
    <div class="carousel_bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-keyboard="true">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <?php
                    $active = 'active';
                    $num = 0;
                    while ( have_rows('photos') ) : the_row();
                    $photo = get_sub_field('photo');
                    if($photo == "" ) continue;
                        ?>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $num ?>" class="<?php echo $active ?>"></li>
                        <?php
                        $active = '';
                        $num += 1;
                    endwhile; ?>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <?php
                    $active = 'active';
                    while ( have_rows('photos') ) : the_row();
                    $photo = get_sub_field('photo');
                    if($photo == "" ) continue;
                        ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $active ?> screen08">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/files/photos/<?php the_sub_field('photo'); ?>" class="img-fluid is-slider-item" />
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /item -->
                        <?php $active = '';
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Bootstrap 4 js library is loaded properly ...

Any hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include links or CDN and versions of Bootstrap CSS, JS and jQuery? Also, does data-keyboard="true" work without controls?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on this but could it be that he *data-keyboard* info needs to be attached to the *carousel-item* rather than *carousel-example-generic*? Just something to try.

After thought....

OK so I notice some incorrect documentation at GetBootstrap. In Bootstrap 5 it is meant to be *data-bs-keyboard* not *data-keyboard*.

Worth a try :)

Comment: tried and it did not worked

Comment: Edited and added another suggestion for you.

Comment: I tried also that but as I am using Bootstrap 4 it will not work